# Sweave, Shiny : can't generate a PDF on the server

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, sweave, generate

I'm working on `R Sweave`  to generate a report in PDF in a `shiny`  application on a server. Everything works perfectly in my computer, locally, I can generate my PDF in the application. It also works in the server. But, when I wanted to add an image in a background, a rectangular header, in the `R Sweave` , it didn't work anymore on the server, it can't be generated.

Here's the code I added in my `R Sweave`, so my report :

```
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\backgroundsetup{
   scale=0.5,
   angle=0,
   opacity=1,
   color=black,
   contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node at ([yshift=-.6in] current page.north)
            {\includegraphics[width = \paperwidth]{myheader}};
     \end{tikzpicture}}
 }
```

Did I forget something ?

Thank you

**EDIT** : After some researches, I think I probably have a problem with these functions in the script `server.R` :

```
output$report <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function(){name()},
  content = function(file) {
    out = knitr::knit2pdf(input="my_report.Rnw",encoding = "UTF-8",clean=TRUE)
    file.rename(out, file)
    file.copy(file,paste0("export/",Sys.Date(),"_",name()))
  },

  contentType = 'application/pdf'
)
```

It seems that I probably forgot an argument in my function `out = knitr::knit2pdf(input="my_report.Rnw",encoding = "UTF-8",clean=TRUE)`. It seems that it can only manage a text on UTF-8 and geometric forms, not an image.

Comment: We'd need the error message you see. Also first things first: some servers simply do _not_ have a full texlive installation.

Comment: It displays: "File not found, Firefox cannot find the file at the address http://...."

Comment: And just to cover the obvious: you reference a file `myheader`.  Do you have such a file in the current directory?

Comment: Yes, there's an image, there's no problem at this point.

Comment: I just add a new part on the topic.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say with "there is an image". You tell latex that a file `myheader` (no extension) is to to included.  You must then supply such a file.   Lastly, you have a 10-line segment there that breaks.  Maybe debug it to a 3 line segment (ie just `\includegraphics` first, then tikz and so on.  This is why we usually ask for [minimally complete verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which your question did not supply.

Comment: Sorry, I answered quickly and I didn't detail enough. The code in the 1st part of the topic is in my R Sweave, so the report I want to generate. I want to generate it through a Shiny app, which is the 2nd part of code (in the EDIT). My report generate perfectly apart from the Shiny app (if I execute it locally). It won't generate through the Shiny app and I think it's because of this function "knitr::knit2pdf(input="my_report.Rnw",encoding = "UTF-8",clean=TRUE)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! In my R Sweave, I just added \usepackage{tikz} and it works!

Thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel for his help.